# Why would frames drop considerably the longer a Unity Game runs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2020.3.4f1 to create a 2D game for mobile.

I created a map builder for the game.
When I hit play, it makes a bunch of 'maps' that are saved as json files. The longer the game plays seems to result in extremely slow frame rates (200fps -> 2 fps) based on the stats menu while the game is running.

The strange thing is if I go to the "Scene" tab and left click on a sprite the fps instantly jumps back up again.

### Screenshots

The problem seems related to taking screenshots within Unity.
The big bulge happens & only resets when I un-pause the game.
[image]

### Questions

- Why would the frame rates drop considerably over time the longer the game is running?
- Why would the frame rate jump back up after selecting a sprite in the "Scene" tab?
- What happens in Unity when selecting a sprite in the "Scene" tab? Is there a garbage collection method?

### Script:

```
private void Awake()
{
    myCamera = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
    instance = this;
    width = 500;
    height = 500;
}

private void OnPostRender()
{
    if(takeScreenShotOnNextFrame)
    {
        takeScreenShotOnNextFrame = false;
        RenderTexture renderTexture = myCamera.targetTexture;

        Texture2D renderResult = new Texture2D(renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false); 
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, renderTexture.width, renderTexture.height);
        renderResult.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0);

        float myValue = 0;
        float totalPixels = renderResult.width * renderResult.height;

        for (int i = 0; i < renderResult.width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < renderResult.height; j++)
            {
                Color myColor = renderResult.GetPixel(i, j);
                myValue += myColor.r;
                //Debug.Log("Pixel (" + i + "," + j + "): " + myColor.r);
            }
        }

        occlusion = ((myValue / totalPixels) * 100);

        byte[] byteArray = renderResult.EncodeToPNG();

        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/ScreenShots/CameraScreenshot.png", byteArray);

        // Cleanup
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(renderTexture);
        myCamera.targetTexture = null;
        renderResult = null;
    }
}

private void TakeScreenshot(int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
{
    width = screenWidth;
    height = screenHeight;

    if(myCamera.targetTexture != null)
    {
        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(myCamera.targetTexture);
        //Debug.Log("Camera target texture null: " + myCamera.targetTexture == null);
    }

    myCamera.targetTexture = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(width, height, 16);
    takeScreenShotOnNextFrame = true;
}

public static void TakeScreenshot_Static(int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
{
    instance.TakeScreenshot(screenWidth, screenHeight);
}
```

}

Comment: What happens if you disable the screenshot code?  Unity has a pretty good out-of-the-box performance analysis module that can assist you right down to the frame level.   Suggest you use that or at least major parts you think might be slowing it down.  Impossible to tell otherwise without code and given the nature you really cant post the whole app here

Comment: I used the profiler tool and it does show the increase in fps from it. Oddly, when I unpause to go back it seems to return the frames to normal.

Comment: Thank-you for your edit and screenshots :)